# bash summing and grouping a column

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sum, cut

hey guys so i have this dummy data :

```
 id  | game_title     | demography    | store|sold(in k)| game_id|
+----+----------------+---------------+------+----------+--------+
|  3 | final fantasy  | 3             | QLD  | 5        | 115    |
|  4 | final fantasy  | 3             | NSW  | 3        | 115    |
|  5 | tekken         | 2             | QLD  | 2        | 101    |
|  6 | tekken         | 2             | QLD  | 1.5      | 101    |
|  7 | sfv            | 1             | NSW  | 1        | 100    |
|  8 | final fantasy  | 3             | QLD  | 2        | 115    |
|  9 | fifa           | 1             | QLD  | 12       | 102    |
+----+----------------+---------------+------+----------+--------+
```

The desired result shown below:

```
id   | game_title     | sold total in k|
+----+----------------+----------------|
|  3 | final fantasy  | 10             |   
|  4 | tekken         | 3.5            |    
|  5 | sfv            | 1              |     
|  6 | fifa           | 12             |      
+----+----------------+----------------+
```

The game_id will be used as a group since some title does have a same title, how would i do this using bash ?

i can select the game_title, sold and game_id by using

```
awk -F "," '{print $2 $5 $6}' data.csv
```

however i'm not too sure how to sum then grouping it.

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts here, 1 question I have, could you please how come `3..4..5..6` came in output? Ideally they should be the their respective values from Input_file right? Kindly explain more on it, I haven't consider that in my codes.

Comment: ah that's a mistake on my part it should show 3,5,7,9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

***Solution 1st:*** This will give you output in same order in which your Input_file's 2nd field is present.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   FS="|"
   OFS="| "
}
FNR==1{
   print
   next
}
/--/ && !val{
   val=$0
   next
}
!c[$3]++{
   d[++count]=$3
}
{
   a[$3]+=$6
   if(!b[$3]){
     b[$3]=$2 OFS $3
   }
}
END{
   print val
   for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
      if(a[d[i]] && d[i]){
        print OFS b[d[i]],a[d[i]]
      }
   }
   print val
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
 id  | game_title     | demography    | store|sold(in k)| game_id|
+----+----------------+---------------+------+----------+--------+
|   3 |  final fantasy  | 10
|   5 |  tekken         | 3.5
|   7 |  sfv            | 1
|   9 |  fifa           | 12
+----+----------------+---------------+------+----------+--------+
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you are NOT worried about order of 2nd column in output then following may help you.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   FS="|"
   OFS="| "
}
FNR==1{
   print
   next
}
/--/ && !val{
   val=$0
   next
}
{
   a[$3]+=$6
   if(!b[$3]){
     b[$3]=$2 OFS $3
   }
}
END{
   print val
   for(i in a){
     if(a[i] && b[i]){
       print OFS b[i],a[i]
     }
   }
   print val
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
 id  | game_title     | demography    | store|sold(in k)| game_id|
+----+----------------+---------------+------+----------+--------+
|   7 |  sfv            | 1
|   3 |  final fantasy  | 10
|   5 |  tekken         | 3.5
|   9 |  fifa           | 12
+----+----------------+---------------+------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i'm not too sure why but when i tried to run both of the code you gave me it only return
id,title,demography,store,sold,game_id

Comment: @user3646742, I am getting correct output with both the codes let me update output too now in my post. Is your actual Input_file is same as shown samples? If yes then try to check `cat -v Input_file` too to see if control M characters are there if yes then remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' Input_file > temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file`, let me know how it goes?

Comment: @user3646742, Cool then, check codes and let me know then it should work.

Comment: As you suspected, there's an control M character in the game.csv file. so i remove it using the dos2unix on the csv and the .sh i made using the code you gave me. However it still doesn't work. Also tried not using the .sh just using it directly still doesn't show any change

Comment: @user3646742, BINGO, I knew it. Please check my edit with output which I pasted I am getting correctly. I am using delimiters as `|` so make sure your Input_file is having `|` in it as delimiter. Now let us check your Input_file again if it is NOT same as shown sample then it will issue, could you please confirm if your file is same as shown samples?

Comment: ahhh the delimiters is actually ',' the one i made is only for illustration purposes, my bad. After changing the OFS and FS to ',' it does work thanks :)

Comment: @user3646742, give it a shot by changing `FS` value to `,` and let me know then?

Comment: ah yeah i'm about to do that. However why is the output doesn't show the fifa ? it shows the following:

id,title,demography,store,sold,game_id

 sfv 1 202
 tekken 2 202
 final fantasy 3 345.

Comment: @user3646742, not sure what is happening from your end, I could see `|   9 |  fifa           | 12` in my output?

Comment: ah fixed it, something wrong with how i changed the input file. Thanks :), btw do you have a recommendation resources for this kind of topic ? still very new with bash and need to learn more of it

Comment: @user3646742, to be honest I will say read O’Reilly book for `awk` and BEST place for learning is SO itself try answering or observing the answers here. Try your best to solve your problems then when you feel you can't you could get guidance here(but efforts are mandatory as we all are here to learn).